# Is it possible to update deep link instead of creating a new one?

Tags: branch.io

I use Branch.io in my project, where users can invite their friends. For this I let them create deep link. Sometimes users may want to change their "invitations", so I would like to let them update the parameters of the deep links already created. I know it is possible in the dashboard (if the link was also created there), but can't find if it possible with iOS/Android sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Updating link is not possible when links are created via Branch Universal Object.

What you can do is to create a new link when the invitation is edited and purge the old link via code.